# MySQL - What is the difference between SUM and COUNT?

Tags: mysql, count, sum

In MySQL - What is the difference between using SUM or COUNT?

```
SELECT SUM(USER_NAME =  'JoeBlow') 

SELECT COUNT(USER_NAME =  'JoeBlow')
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### It is a big difference because the result is not the same.

The first query returns the number of times the condition is true, because `true` is `1` and `false` is  `0`.

The second query returns the complete record count because `count()` does not care about the content inside it, as long as the content is NOT NULL. Because `count(1)` and `count(0)` are still values and both get counted.

To get the correct return value for the second query you would have to make the result of the condition be `null` (instead of `0`) to not being counted. Like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(case when USER_NAME = 'JoeBlow' then 'no matter what' else NULL end) 
from your_table
```

<sub>Or simply remove the `else` part from the `case` statement which automatically makes the `else` part `null`.</sub>

Answer (score 32):

To answer the OP question more direct and literal, consider if you were totalling integers in your column instead of strings.

```
+----+------+
| id | vote |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  2 |   -1 |
|  3 |    1 |
|  4 |   -1 |
|  5 |    1 |
+----+------+
```

COUNT = 5 votes

SUM = 1 vote
 *(-2 + 3 = 1)*

Sum is doing the mathematical sum, whereas count simply counts any value as 1 regardless of what data type.

Answer (score 1):

I guess COUNT() returns the number of rows in a column whereas SUM() returns the sum for the column

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer - the fact that `COUNT` counts and `SUM` sums was already provided in other answers, and there's no need to repeat that unless you have to add some new insights

Answer (score -1):

```
select count(field) from table
```

is slower than

```
select sum(1) from table
```

Consider using the second option